# Unity 2D Animation Won't Play after SetActive(true)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, isenabled, animator

I have a 2D single screen style game where I have a disabled gameobject. Under this are several children that that are animated. The parent object holds the animator for the children. When I enabled the parent, the animations will not play. The animator looks as thought it's trying to processes the default entry state but does not complete. I've done some research on this and it seems that disabling and then enabling something does not start the animator. I've tried writing some code for it with no luck and setting the sprite renderer false won't work either as there are simply too many sprites. Here's my last attempt:    Any ideas?

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class animationState : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator anim;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        if (anim.gameObject.activeSelf)
        {
            anim.Play("pinWheelAnimation");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unity doesn't work like that, You can't set an **animator** to the parent object that is going to influence **animations** from children, you are going to have to set up an animator for every child. If you want to modify animators of children from a parent object you can do that with a script that searches for all children and their  components and changes their parameters.

Take a look at this: [Animator parameters](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html)

Comment: Maybe I explained it wrong. There's only the parent object that has an animator/animation that essentially key frames the child objects. This works fine. It's only when the object is set active that the animation fails to load. If I were to leave it active, it would play and switch states as needed. The problem is it is inactive at start and upon activation, the animation never plays. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set an IdleState as DefaultState with no exit time and no animation and define a trigger event to go over to your animation state. Then activate the trigger in

```
void Start()
{
}
```

Comment: I'll check it out and let you know! Thanks!!